# C and C++ Code Interoperability - Data Passing Issues

Tags: c++, c, interop

The following is the situation. There is a system/software which is completely written in C. This C program spawns a new thread to start some kind of a data processing engine written in C++. Hence, the system which I have, runs 2 threads (the main thread and the data processing engine thread). Now, I have written some function in C which takes in a C struct and passes it to the data processing thread so that a C++ function can access the C struct. While doing so, I am observing that the values of certain fields (like unsigned int) in the C struct changes when being accessed in the C++ side and I am not sure why. At the same time, if I pass around a primitive data type like an int, the value does not change. It would be great if someone can explain me why it behaves like this. The following is the code that i wrote.
`

```
/* C++ Function */
void DataProcessor::HandleDataRecv(custom_struct* cs)
{
  /*Accesses the fields in the structure cs - an unsigned int field. The value of   
    field here is different from the value when accessed through the C function below.
   */
}

/*C Function */
void forwardData(custom_struct* cs)
{
  dataProcessor->HandleDataRecv(cs); //Here dataProcessor is a reference to the object 
                                     //of the C++ class.
}
```

`
Also, both these functions are in different source files(one with .c ext and other with .cc ext)

Comment: what platform are you running your code on? Which compiler/linker family?

Comment: i am running my code on linux and using gcc to compile both the C and C++ files

Comment: Are you sure you're not compiling your C++ files with g++?

Comment: Also, please show the relevant code. I suspect that it's a problem with `thiscall` convention, but that's just a gut feeling. I can't verify unless I see code.

Comment: `unsigned int` *is* a primitive type. On the same compiler, OS and target CPU there's no way it's incompatible between C and C++.

Comment: `unsigned int` might be a primitive, but a struct containing an `unsigned int` sure isn't, and that's where he was drawing the distinction.  My guesses here are that it has something to do with the C function being not-quite-as-reentrant-as-he-first-thought, but that's just speculation.  As others have stated, without seeing code we're stabbing in the dark.

Comment: So what you're saying is, your C++ function sees a different struct than your C function, even when you can otherwise guarantee the struct is the same?  Is it possible that the other thread is modifying the structure in between calls?

Comment: Please also show the struct declaration.

Answer (score 3):

I'd check that both sides layout the struct in the same

- print `sizeof(custom_struct)` in both languages
- Create an instance of custom_struct in both languages and print the offset of
  each member variable.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I shall try that out.

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess would be Michael Andresson is right, structure aligment might be the issue.

Try to compile both c and c++ files with

```
-fpack-struct=4
```

(or some other number for 4). This way, the struct is aligned the same in every case.

If we could see the struct declaration, it would probably clearer. The struct does not contain any #ifdef with c++-specific code like a constructor, does it? Also, check for `#pragma pack` directives which manipulate data alignment.

Answer (score 0):

(CORRECTION) With minor exceptions, C++ is a superset of C (meaning C89),  So i'm confused about what is going on.  I can only assume it has something to do with how you are passing or typing your variables, and/or the systems they are running on.  It should, technically speaking, unless I am very mistaken, have nothing to do with c/c++ interoperability.

Some more details would help.

Comment: C is not a strict subset of C++. There are many features of C99 for example that didn't make it into C++.

Comment: I am running on a linux system and compiled both the C/C++ source files using gcc compiler. Basically, I am passing a C struct to a C++ function through C wrapper functions which makes a C++ function call. The C++ functions just access the members of this struct.

Comment: How are the values changing ie, have you notice any discernible pattern, is completely random.......  what are the struct types, Are you sure they contain what you think they contain, and what are the c++ functions doing with them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on one side the struct has 'empty bytes' added to make the variables align on 32 bit boundaries for speed (so a CPU register can point to the variable directly).

And on the other side the struct may be packed to conserve space.

Comment: In such a case, if I create a new structure and transform the C structure to this struct through some wrapper, would that work?

Comment: I would first determine if that was the issue.  Most compilers have switches or pragmas to turn byte packing on and off.  You can also manually layout your struct with packing by adding dummy variables.